# Simplify the differential form $d [ A, B]$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

> How can we simplify the differential form in the expanded expression
>   $$
> d [ A, B]=?
> $$
>   Suppose $A$ is $p$-form, and $B$ is $q$-form, and $d$ is exterior derivative.

My attempt: Generally I get
$$d [ A, B]=d (AB-BA)= (d A) B +(-1)^p A (d B)- (d B) A - (-1)^{q} B (d A)$$

if both $p, q$ are even, we have
$d [ A, B]=d (AB-BA)= (d A) B +A (d B)- (d B) A - B (d A)=[(d A), B ]+[A, (d B)],$ thus
$$d [ A, B]=[(d A), B ]+[A, (d B)]$$
when $p, q$ are even integers.

> Do we have a simpler/simple expression for general $p,q$? And how can we refer the $d [ A, B]=?$ in general in terms of $A,B$, $dA$, $dB$?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the commutator in question is the [graded commutator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graded+commutator), i.e., $[A,B]=AB-(-1)^{pq}BA$.  Because in this case, the formula simplifies to 
$$d[A,B]=[dA,B]+(-1)^p[A,dB],$$
which seems nicer than anything you get with the (non-graded) commutator.

Comment: thanks+1, then you modify my commutator to anticommutator $AB+BA$ when $pq$ is odd?

Comment: Yes.  I imagine this is what was meant.